# Run AWS lambda as an IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to run a python project on AWS lambda, but the API (STS:AssumeRole to generate federation URL) which I am trying to call only supports as an IAM user with long-term credentials. It is working on my machine with my IAM keys, but how can I make it run on AWS lambda?

Comment: Why do you wish to call `AssumeRole()` instead of simply assigning the role to the Lambda function? What is the error you are receiving? What permissions are assigned to the original role that is then calling `AssumeRole()`?

Comment: I am trying to achieve this from lambda https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html. It seems that it only works when it is invoked by a valid IAM user credential and lambda invocation works as a service. I gave full permission to lambda role but no luck. I am getting 404 response while requesting signInToken (at step 5 Example Code Using IAM Query API Operations). It is working from my local though.

Comment: how are you executing locally, post the commands or screenshot, it may help us understand what you are trying to do

Comment: As a test, if you temporarily hard-code permanent credentials into the Lambda function to make the `AssumeRole()` call, does the Lambda function work?

Comment: Yeah, it works if I passed the access key and secret access key in the client.
client = boto3.client(
    'sts',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a role that has similar permissions like your local user. And you can attach the role to your lambda to utilize the STS service.